# msql join 2 tables based on 2 values

Tags: mysql, join

im trying to get 2 tables to join based on 2 values. Heres the tables:

**Contacts** vlg debnr name etc.

**orderheaders** vlg debnr ordernumber etc.

vlg is a contactperson number associated with the order. Debnr is the number of the company associated with the order. I only get the ordernumber posted, need to find that in the orderheaders table, find the debnr and vlg and then with that find the name of the contact person. I think this can be done trough INNER JOIN, but I cant get it to work due to my inexperience with JOIN.

Heres what i tried but wont work, I know it wont because im not even checking the vlg, but I dont know how to join based on 2 values. Can anyone please help me?:

```
SELECT *, orderheaders.ordernummer, orderheaders.vlg
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN contacts on( orderheaders.debnr = contacts.debnr)
WHERE orderheaders.ordernummer = 'some_order_number';
```

Comment: `orderheaders` is not in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: You are now using the `ordernumber` that is posted, but you compare it with `debnr`. That is likely to give the wrong results or no results at all. Also, you joined `contacts` on `contacts`, while I think you should join `contacts` on `orderheaders`.

Comment: Please note I removed the PHP code that seems to be irrelevant to your problem. See how the syntax-highlighter now kicks in :)

Comment: sry I simplified the table names and made an error with the last one.

Comment: I guess one of your two `contacts` tables is in fact `orderheaders`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN orderheaders ON (
    orderheaders.debnr = contacts.debnr
    AND orderheaders.vlg = contacts.vlg
)
```

Or, since the fields have the same name in both tables:

```sql
... INNER JOIN orderheaders USING (debnr, vlg)
```

Comment: Thats amazing, thanks a lot! I Was closer then I thought. this has given me a bit more insight into the JOIN function.